# South Django db migration

Tags: database, django, heroku, django-south

Attempted to run:

```
 python manage.py migrate
```

got this error:

```
 django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "my_class" violates foreign key constraint "content_type_id_refs_id_bc63f081"
 DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(0) is not present in table "django_content_type".
```

I'm really not quite sure what's wrong here... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Integrity error means that foreignkey has been affected, or duplicate key exists. Better you drop DB and reconstruct the process if you have  had previous data entries in database. If the error still occurs, please show the model structure.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you specified `0` as the default value in the migration. Delete the migration and run it again, this time specify an empty string as the default.

If you already have some data in the database you'll need to specify `null=True` and `blank=True` in the Foreign-Key or it'll break.

Comment: Thank you. When I delete the migrations from the specific django app, what do I need to run?

Comment: @h4x0rjax run it again, this time specify an empty string as the default value.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not specifying anything as a default value. Here is my model: https://dpaste.de/5Hpt